# Facebook Like Count Discrepancies - Page vs. Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

there is a huge discrepancy between the number of likes our page has received and the number of likes displayed when using the like button, and giving it the facebook page's URL (like button is much higher). Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the doc :

> **What makes up the number shown on my Like button?**
>
> The number shown is the sum of:
>
> - The number of likes of this URL
> - The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
> - The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
> - The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.

Answer (score 2):

I am a Facebook Partner Engineer working on platform. To bring your Facebook page Likes to your web page you should use the Like Box rather than the like button. This will allow you to gain Facebook page likes from your website while also giving you the option to show your page's stream stories right in your web site.

You can find out more about the like box here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

I hope this helps!

Jonathan

Comment: While the Like box might be better, the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) clearly states that it's possible to use the plugin to Like a Facebook Page. One possible reason for the difference the OP is having might be because the Page will display the number of Fans (likes) where the Plugin will display the sum of Likes **AND** other criteria (detailed in the document I linked to), please confirm?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is the like button aggregates likes, comments and other interactions.
Basically the counter next to the button isn't the like count but an activity or interaction count.

You can get the actual like count through the graph api if you need it.